# app can't install after update eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I've build android application using eclipse, everything work well when i change my code and run on emulator before i update my eclipse,after my eclipse update, i change my code, my app didn't install new code but still running previous code and show log like this.

```
[2013-11-25 10:27:07 - ChatKrawala] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2013-11-25 10:27:07 - ChatKrawala] Starting activity com.ltvie.chatkrawala.ChatkraActivity on device S5830ae0c94c8
[2013-11-25 10:27:07 - ChatKrawala] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.ltvie.chatkrawala/.ChatkraActivity }
```

why my eclipse cant install new app when i change my code after i update my eclipse and ADT?

Comment: uninstall app from emulator manually and try running again

Comment: i want update my app with no uninstall previous app.

Comment: either you can force stop it and try run again if you want update

Comment: Try restarting adb, Eclipse, emulator, system, etc. If it still doesn't work, then try starting a different activity by changing the MAIN activity in Manifest. Not sure if it'll work, but worth a try.